# Displaying nested attributes at infowindow on gmaps4rails, resulting in #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails, infowindow

I am making an applicattion that uses gmaps4rails gem which is a simple contact manager with mapping capabilities, so i have the main model by the name person which has

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :details, :gmaps, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :name,    :contacts_attributes
has_many :contacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true

acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address
  address
end

def gmaps4rails_infowindow
 "Name: #{name} <br \>
 #{details}
 //list with symbols of type of contact and contact by itself
 #{contacts. ??? }
 "
end
```

Where my contacts model has three attributes, the persons_id, type (be it email, phone, mobile) and Contact by itself, so how can i pass this to a list inside of infowindow?

Here is an image of how it displays

[image]

And btw, i defined this all in the model and not controller, since it was easier for me at the time...

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the relations between your objects? (`has_one` ...) what do you need as an output?

Comment: My relations are Person has_many :contacts , and contacts belongs_to :person

And what i want for output would be just the contacts type and contacts number or email.. 

Also, i can view all of the contacts in my edit or show view but only cant acess it, or dont know how on the infowindow.

Comment: It simply depends on your contact model. contact.email ?

Comment: I tried, it says.. undefined method `email' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Nothing to do with the gem here. Simply about how you built you're app. Can't help, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reread, you could do:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  text = "Name: #{name} <br/>"
  contacts.each do |contact|
    text << "#{contact.email}..."
  end
  text
end
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a truly awesome rubyist

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderK.A. enjoy working with Ruby, you'll learn quickly ;)